# How do I stop file navigation from going above a certain directory?

Tags: java, android, file-management

I'm quite new to Android so this might be a quirk of the platform that I'm not yet accustomed to, but I'm having an issue with file navigation. I've successfully created a system where I can enter into and navigate out of directories successfully, but I am unable to set my app to disallow navigation above `/storage/emulated/0`. My current code for doing this is:

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
        if(f.getAbsolutePath() != "/storage/emulated/0"){
            RefreshListing(f.getParent());
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
}
```

Where `f` is a variable of type `File` which contains the current directory.

I have tried adding a slash to the end of my compared path, which doesn't make a difference. I have also tried printing `f.getAbsolutePath()` to the screen to make sure I am using the correct syntax, but still the strings do not equate and navigation ends up going past `/storage/emulated/0`, crashing the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, string comparison is via `equals()`, not `==` or `!=`.

Comment: ...I can't believe I made such a simple mistake. I think I've got C# still on my mind. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question :)